# Get existing VPC for use within a Pulumi stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, infrastructure-as-code, pulumi

I'm trying to use Pulumi within a somewhat restricted AWS environment.

This sandbox requires that I use a specific VPC, and there is no default VPC.

I have tried the examples showing how to reference an existing VPC, but they all fail with some variant of "invoking aws:ec2/getVpc:getVpc: no matching VPC found"

@pulumi/awsx, using code referenced from: https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi-awsx/issues/522:

```js
const vpc = awsx.ec2.Vpc.fromExistingIds('name', {
  vpcId: 'id',
  publicSubnetIds: ['a', 'b'],
  privateSubnetIds: ['a', 'b']
})
```

@pulumi/aws, using code referenced from https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/pkg/aws/ec2/getvpc/:

```js
const vpc = aws.ec2.Vpc.get('vpc-1', 'vpc-1')
```

Question: what is the correct and complete syntax for referencing an existing VPC within a Pulumi stack?

Note that I would rather not "adopt" this resource as it is shared and the user running the `pulumi up` command does not have permission to delete VPC resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked in the end:

```js
const vpc = aws.ec2.Vpc.get('vpc-123', 'vpc-123')
```

I don't think I had saved my file correctly before `pulumi up` after making the above change.

Note that I also had to add subnets manually to my ALB to get this working, as below:

```js
const vpc = aws.ec2.Vpc.get('vpc-123', 'vpc-123')

const clusterName = nameResource('graphQlServiceCluster')
const ecsCluster = new awsx.ecs.Cluster(clusterName, {
  name: clusterName,
  vpc
})

const PublicSubnet1a = 'subnet-123'
const PublicSubnet1b = 'subnet-123'

const alb = new awsx.lb.ApplicationLoadBalancer(nameResource('graphQlServiceElb'), {
  name: nameResource('graphQlServiceElb'),
  external: true,
  vpc,
  subnets: [
    PublicSubnet1a,
    PublicSubnet1b

  ]
})
const listener = alb.createListener(nameResource('graphqlServiceListener'), {
  name: nameResource('graphqlServiceListener'),
  port: 80,
  external: true,
  vpc
})
```

Comment: The "trick" (for me) was passing the `subnets` argument to `awsx.lb.ApplicationLoadBalancer`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a subtle difference between `getVpc()` that you linked to and `Vpc.get()` that you tried using. You should use the former:

```ts
const vpc = aws.ec2.getVpc({ id: yourVpcId });
```

Answer (score 1):

Pulumi has multiple `Vpc` types. **You probably want to use the `awsx` VPC as it's higher level (and required to use other awsx infrastructure).**

There's two ways to do this:

#### Creating a new VPC

```
const vpc = new awsx.ec2.Vpc(config.vpcName, {
  cidrBlock: "10.0.0.0/16",
  subnets: [
    {
      name: "public",
      type: "public",
      location: {
        cidrBlock: "10.0.0.0/24",
        availabilityZone: "us-east-2a",
      },
    },
    {
      name: "private-a",
      type: "private",
      location: {
        cidrBlock: "10.0.1.0/24",
        availabilityZone: "us-east-2a",
      },
    },
    {
      name: "private-b",
      type: "private",
      location: {
        cidrBlock: "10.0.2.0/24",
        availabilityZone: "us-east-2b",
      },
    },
  ],
});
```

#### Using an existing VPC

Borrowing from this [GitHub thread with the Pulumi CTO](https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi-awsx/issues/430#issuecomment-543246212) produced a correct result:

```js
  const vpc = awsx.ec2.Vpc.fromExistingIds("mycompany", {
    vpcId: "vpc-myvpcid",
  });

  // Create an ECS Fargate cluster.
  const ecsCluster = new awsx.ecs.Cluster("mycompany-pulumi-cluster", {
    vpc,
  });
```